# Swift - Does controlTextDidChange Work With NSTextView?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextview

I have one text field and one textView.  The controlTextDidChange method responds to a text field change.  But it doesn't respond to a textview change.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject,NSApplicationDelegate,NSTextFieldDelegate,NSTextViewDelegate {
    func applicationWillFinishLaunching(notification:NSNotification) {
        /* delegates */
        textField.delegate = self
        textView.delegate = self    
    }

    override func controlTextDidChange(notification:NSNotification?) {
        if notification?.object as? NSTextField == textField {
            print("good")
        }
        else if notification?.object as? NSTextView == textView {
            print("nope")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running Xcode 7.2.1 under Yosemite.  Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`controlTextDidChange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/controlTextDidChange:) is a method of `NSControl` class which is inherited by `NSTextField`, but not by `NSTextView`:

[image]

Because of that, instances of **NSTextView** can't receive the above callback.

I think you should implement [`textDidChange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTextDelegate/textDidChange:) from `NSTextViewDelegate` protocol instead:

```
func textDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
  if notification.object == textView {
    print("good")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought controlTextDidChange responds to an NSTextView change in Objective-C.